# Update score on mysql databse only if submitted score is higher than the existing one

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I use the following PHP to update the score for a particular quiz number where the username is equal to the current session username. Quiz number and score come from javascript via an ajax function.

```
$score = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['score']);

$QuizNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['QuizNumber'])

$sql="UPDATE users

SET $QuizNumber='$score'

WHERE username='".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'";
```

This works fine, however I am trying to include a conditional statement that only updates the score if the existing score on the database is less than the score being submitted.

This is the statement I have tried including but with no success:

```
if (['QuizNumber'] < $_POST['score'])
```

How do I get $QuizNumber to be set equal to submitted score only when it is higher than the existing database score?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You can retrieve the score from database and after use a conditional to know if the sent value is higher than the database score.

Comment: or You can add the condition to your query!

Comment: And ['QuizNumber'] will never work. You didn't specify to where it belongs and you aren't doing a query to retrieve the database score.

Comment: And you used `$QuizNumber` in your query which I think you meant something else like a column name.

Comment: You should better use prepared Statements instead of string concatenation. Is the column indeed a variable? mysqli_real_escape_string does not escape identifiers like column names.

Comment: In my case $QuizNumber gets a variable from the ajax query so it ends up being equal to Quiz1 which is a column in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
$score = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['score']);
$QuizNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['QuizNumber'])

$sql="UPDATE users
SET $QuizNumber = '$score'
WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['MM_Username']."'
AND $QuizNumber < '$score'";
```

Comment: Vote up. But if the score be an integer, you must remember to remove single quotes from < '$score';

Comment: @MarceloCamargo No need for that, query would work with single quotes!

Comment: Wow, that was mindbogglingly simple. Thank you for the help Linger. I love to over-complicate!